# Code is working on older version of urllib3 package (1.6) but not on latest version (2.0.4)

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, urllib3

I have a code, which logging me into server. The code is working on older version of `Urllib3` (1.6), but is not working on latest version (2.0.4). What do I have to change for making it work on latest version ?

Here is my code that handles ssl:

```
import requests
import urllib3

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += ':HIGH:!DH:!aNULL'
try:
    requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += ':HIGH:!DH:!aNULL'
except AttributeError:
    # no pyopenssl support used / needed / available
    pass
```

Here is the error on latest version:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\xxx\xxx\Desktop\request\rqst_01.py", line 38, in <module>
    requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += ':HIGH:!DH:!aNULL'
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'urllib3.util.ssl_' has no attribute 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS'
```

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean?

Comment: Code throw errors. One of them is that dh key is too small.

Comment: I have voted to put your question on hold for missing debug information. Please update your question with the full error message including the full error traceback if available. A vague description like yours is not helpful to analyze the problem.

Comment: I have updated question with error.